# HDMI port only works on 1 monitor (or just very picky) (Dell Precision 5530)

Tags: laptop, display, hdmi, dvi

I just got a Dell 5530 (p2000, intel, no Optimus).

The HDMI port only works on 1 monitor. This is coincidentally the 1 first monitor I ever plugged into it on HDMI. This is using DVI-D to HDMI. If I use any other monitor through the HDMI port (although my tv works) it does not work. I've plugged it into 5 of the same monitor, and it will only output on the first one. USB-C to DP works fine no matter what.

All these monitors are the same brand and model and whenever I try to use another monitor that isn't the one that works, it goes to power-saving mode. I can see "something" is detected considering if I take the HDMI cable out it says nothing is detected when I plug it back in, it goes into power-saving mode. I can also sometimes get it to show in xrandr before it conks back out to not detecting the display.

I've disabled/blacklisted my nvidia card and confirmed i'm only using intel (as I've swapped about numerous times), even tried the opposite and it is still the same. I've changed from gdm3 to lightdm, although i'm past the point now thinking this is my OS.

I've tried ruling out drivers here as well using multiple (both prop, open-source) having tried numerous live CD's and installed another Linux distro on another partition, and even then it still only works on the 1 monitor.

I'm wondering how I can isolate this down, it's starting to look like a laptop issue to me if this is happening on numerous live CD's and even windows now. The BIOS has been flashed to the latest version.

I'm totally confused here, as to why it only likes the 1 monitor, maybe some form of stored device profile? Any help pinpointing this issue (as it's now clearly past my level of understanding when it goes down into hardware stuff) would be appreciated.

With the monitors that go into power saving mode with HDMI (DC/CI is enabled with all the monitors, however, it is enabled on all the ones that worked, swapped between the 2 / factory reset the monitors anyway). Nothing happens when I plug it in.

When i plug it into the monitor that does work (using tail -f /var/log/{messages,kernel,dmesg,syslog}):

`Sep 16 13:34:17 ntyze-frxps /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2741]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SHP", prod id 5274
Sep 16 13:34:17 ntyze-frxps /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2741]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Sep 16 13:34:17 ntyze-frxps /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2741]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  142.52  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1142 -hsync -vsync (68.5 kHz eP)
Sep 16 13:34:17 ntyze-frxps /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2741]: (II) modeset(0): Allocate new frame buffer 3840x1200 stride
Sep 16 13:34:18 ntyze-frxps /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2741]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SHP", prod id 5274
Sep 16 13:34:18 ntyze-frxps /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2741]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Sep 16 13:34:18 ntyze-frxps /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2741]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  142.52  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1142 -hsync -vsync (68.5 kHz eP)
Sep 16 13:34:18 ntyze-frxps /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2741]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SHP", prod id 5274
Sep 16 13:34:18 ntyze-frxps /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2741]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Sep 16 13:34:18 ntyze-frxps /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2741]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  142.52  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1142 -hsync -vsync (68.5 kHz eP)
Sep 16 13:34:18 ntyze-frxps gsd-color[2279]: no xrandr-Dell Inc.-DELL U2412M-30WJ16160JCL device found: Failed to find output xrandr-Dell Inc.-DELL U2412M-30WJ16160JCL
Sep 16 13:34:18 ntyze-frxps /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2741]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SHP", prod id 5274
Sep 16 13:34:18 ntyze-frxps /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2741]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Sep 16 13:34:18 ntyze-frxps /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2741]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  142.52  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1142 -hsync -vsync (68.5 kHz eP)`

Comment: With Linux at least you have a chance to debug what is going on - look at `dmesg`, `Xorg.log`, and there are also some endpoints in `/sys` where you can directly access HDMI hardware info. What happens if you cold-boot your Dell (turn off, unplug PSU, take out battery, plugin PSU again, then boot) with one of the non-working monitors attached before you plugin the PSU?

Comment: @dirkt, quite literally nothing of value in the xorg logs and dmesg unfortunately.  Should have pointed out I've done cold boots :) Battery is however integrated. I will do some debugging and see if I can grab anything verbose.

Comment: @dirkt, I updated the OP :). Odd, nothing gets spewed out at all. Xorg wasn't any different.

Comment: Connect a working monitor, have a look at `/sys/class/drm/card*` and find the one that corresponds to the HDMI output by looking at `status` and `enabled`. Then look at `edid` and `modes`. Do you get *anything* there for the non-working monitors?

Comment: Whats odd is this works on the U2412MC's i can find, not any B's. Which is odd, because the factory ID should really not have a bearing on this. I would assume later models have later firmware however, which may indicate a firmware issue.

Comment: Quite possible - and the firmware may be responsible for HDMI protocol handshakes and/or EDID.

Comment: Just to come back to this. Dell admitted to a firmware problem - they aren't issuing a fix :) In fact they stopped replying to me and just sent me a dock.

Comment: So I guess you can write an answer now ...